# "Today I've darkened 59 appropriate circles"?

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense

Is this a proper past tense?

> Today I've darkened 59 appropriate circles.

Comment: What are you asking? Can you provide some context?

Comment: Can you please improve this question? Provide context and what you want to achieve. EDIT: @Steve beat me to it :D

Comment: For the love of Archimedes, just don't disturb them.

Comment: @Alenanno, people always seem to beat you to it.

Comment: @Third Idiot: Should I answer seriously?

Comment: @Better do it in the chat. Less chances of getting flagged;)

Answer (score 5):

That sentence is grammatically absolutely correct.  *I’ve darkened* is indeed one kind of past tense; specifically, it’s what’s known (depending on how technical one’s being) as the **perfect tense** or the **simple present perfect tense**, and also by various other terms.  Expanding it to *I have darkened*, *have* is an auxiliary verb, and *darkened* is a past participle.

The sentence is also completely confusing out of context — I have no idea what it’s supposed to mean.  Was that deliberate?  I’m reminded somewhat of Chomsky’s “[colourless green ideas sleep furiously](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously)”.  **Edit:** Stuart Bentley in comments points out a [very plausible context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_Mark_Recognition).

Comment: Somewhat is important; Chomsky is attempting semantical nonsense, and in case of OP semantic can easily be justified: if there are 60 circles on the screen, out which one is not appropriate (it is black) and others are too bright then you could *darken 59 appropriate circles* (there are no intrinsically i.e. semantically contradicting adjectives or verbs).

Comment: Darkening appropriate circles = http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_Mark_Recognition

Comment: @Stuart: Ah! Thankyou — in light of that it makes much more sense.

Comment: @Stuart - indeed, the first thing I thought of when I saw the question was the SAT.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly "I have darkened" is a *perfect tense* using the *past particple*; some people would call it the *present perfect*.  By contrast, "I darkened" would be a *past tense*; some people would call it the *simple past* and others the *preterite*.

Wikipedia has an article on [past tenses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Past_tense).